# How do i read windows registry by JS?

Tags: javascript, registry, activex, activexobject

```
<script>
function showme(){
    var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var value = WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\Tills");
}
</script>
```

I try the above code but not getting any postive result , i got and error that i mention below 
"Automation server can't create object"

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: What browser you are using?

Comment: @user1516873 google chrome ?

Comment: Did you get that specific error from Google Chrome? Because I highly doubt that. At best `ActiveXObject` is supported in Internet Explorer and then only when you lowered its security fence by enabling *Initialize and script active x controls is not marked safe for scripting* in the Internet Settings.

Comment: this error is from IE11 but i want to implement in chrome , but unfortunately it is not working IE also and i did that setting but yet no good news.

Answer (score 0):

Query WMI using Java script to help.